# Measures in differential form

Tags: measure-theory

I came across a question recently where I needed to verify that a given measure (in 'differential' form i.e., given as $d \mu =$ some function of $(x_1, \dotsc x_n)$ times $ \prod_{i \leq n} dx_i$) is a Haar measure. I am not able to get anywhere close to proving it. I don't understand the connection between such a measure and a measure given as a function from the set of measurable subsets to $\mathbb{R}$. Can somebody help me with this?